# What code should I use if all the letter guessed it right?

Tags: c#

I am creating a hangman game and the game is playable but when I guessed all the letters there is no winning messagebox and also it didn't reset the game. See my codes below.

```
namespace Hangman

{

public partial class Form1 : Form

{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string wurds = "";
    List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
    int tries = 0;

    void DrawingHangman()
    {
        Graphics g = pnl1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 10);
        pbHead.Hide();
        pbBody.Hide();
        pbLegs.Hide();
        pbArms.Hide();

    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawingHangman();
        MakeLabels();

    }

    enum BodyParts
    {
        head,
        body,
        legs,
        arms
    }
    void DrawBodyParts(BodyParts bp)
    {
        Graphics g = pnl1.CreateGraphics();
        if (bp == BodyParts.head)
        {
            pbHead.Show();
        }
        else if (bp == BodyParts.body)
        {
            pbBody.Show();
        }
        else if (bp == BodyParts.legs)
        {
            pbLegs.Show();
        }
        else if (bp == BodyParts.arms)
        {
            pbArms.Show();
        }
    }
    void MakeLabels()
    {
        wurds = GetRandomWords();
        Char[] chars = wurds.ToCharArray();
        int between = 330 / chars.Length - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            labels.Add(new Label());
            labels[i].Location = new Point((i * between) + 10, 80);
            labels[i].Text = "_";
            labels[i].Parent = gbWords;
            labels[i].BringToFront();
            labels[i].CreateControl();

        }
        label1.Text = ("Word Length: " + chars.Length).ToString();
    }
    string GetRandomWords()
    {
        string[] wrds = new string[3];
        wrds[0] = "hello";
        wrds[1] = "world";
        Random ran = new Random();
        return wrds[ran.Next(0, wrds.Length - 1)];
    }

void btnLetter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            char letter = textBox1.Text.ToLower().ToCharArray()[0];

            if (!char.IsLetter(letter))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You didn't put a letter. Please input a single letter", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }

    //What do you want it to do that it isn't already when someone wins?
            if (wurds.Contains(letter))
            {
                char[] letters = wurds.ToCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (letters[i] == letter)
                        labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();
                }
                foreach (Label l in labels)
                {
                    if (l.Text == "_") return;
                    MessageBox.Show("You've guess one letter!", "Correct");
                    return;

                }
                ResetGame();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Letter!", "Careful");
                label2.Text += " " + letter.ToString() + ",";
                DrawBodyParts((BodyParts)tries);
                tries++;
                if (tries == 5)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You've been abducted by the gay alien! The answer is : " + wurds, "You Lose", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                    ResetGame();
                }


            }

        }

        void ResetGame()
        {
            GetRandomWords();
            MakeLabels();
            label2.Text = "Missed: ";
            textBox1.Text = "";
            DrawingHangman();
            tries = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the rest of that form code in here (like you did briefly). It provides the necessary context.

Comment: I've done editing it. please take a look thank you @RobM :)

Comment: I see what you did -- which is ok this time... but what I meant was add the additional question within the body, such as at the bottom of the existing one -- so that my answer to your original still makes sense. :)  Please paste the full partial form code in, instead of just this snippet.

Comment: I'm very sorry is this okay now sir? i am very 
faintly discern when it comes to english. @RobM

Comment: Yes. That is better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are resetting the tries... so you are probably ending up with a value for which there is no (BodyParts)...

Add to your ResetGame method:

```
tries = 0;
```

**--- For part 2 of your question: ---**
(until I see the code for the whole form, I'm not sure, but this will at least get you close)
To handle the game winning scenario, try this:

```
        //guessing right letter code here
        if (wurds.Contains(letter))
        {
            char[] letters = wurds.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
            {
                if (letters[i] == letter)
                    labels[i].Text = letter.ToString();
            }

            // determine how many letters have not been guessed yet
            int lettersNotGuessed = 0;
            foreach (Label l in labels)
            {
                if (l.Text == "_") lettersNotGuessed++;
            }

            // Perform correct action: still more to guess or they won
            if (lettersNotGuessed == 0) {
                MessageBox.Show("You Won!", "Correct");                    
                ResetGame();
                return;
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("You've guessed one letter!", "Correct");
            }    
            return;
        }
```

And while you are at it, it's good to handle scenarios where things could go unexpectedly wrong (you'll learn more about error handling later), but this will help for now:

```
void DrawBodyParts(BodyParts bp)
{
    Graphics g = pnl1.CreateGraphics();
    if (bp == BodyParts.head)
    {
        pbHead.Show();
    }
    else if (bp == BodyParts.body)
    {
        pbBody.Show();
    }
    else if (bp == BodyParts.legs)
    {
        pbLegs.Show();
    }
    else if (bp == BodyParts.arms)
    {
        pbArms.Show();
    }
    // something went wrong, let me know about it
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: I can't determine the proper body part to draw.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already declared int tries = 0; inside public form on my codes.

Comment: You are only initializing the value when the form loads -- the first time. Since you aren't resetting it when you reset the game, it keeps on incrementing.

Comment: Also, add a final `else` in your `DrawBodyParts` method and have it throw up a `MessageBox.Show("Error: I can't determine which body part to draw.");`

Comment: It works bro!! by the way i have one last problem what code should i put when the all the letters are guessed? i tried putting else below the foreach but i got an error.

Comment: @Mark Of course it does, so please vote up and accept my answer.  ;)   To help with your follow-up question, edit your question and post the full form code, as I can't see it any longer.  What do you want it to do that it isn't already when someone wins? (put that in the question too)

Comment: oh i see! i get it now! thank you for being very patient sir! how can i give you infinite vote? hehe just kidding! thank you sir very much!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words, Mark. :)  Glad I could help -- just 'pay it forward' with a kind deed for someone else.  Keep on coding and best of luck!